# How to show all nodes of gwt celltree when showMore clicked?

Tags: gwt, tree

I have a simple GWT CellTree with usual defaultNodeSize of 25. Actually my CellTree could have about 100-150 nodes, so to see all of them I have to click "Show more" multiple times. I want to make this CellTree shows all nodes when clicking "Show more".

Is there any way to do that? 
So my final solution is create CustomCellTree which extends CellTree and override onBrowserEvent(Event) method:

```
@Override
public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
    if (event.getType().equals("mousedown")) {
        EventTarget target = event.getEventTarget();
        Element showMore = (Element)this.getElement().getLastChild().getFirstChild().getLastChild();
        // HARDCODE
        if(showMore.toString().replace("display: none;", "").equals(target.toString())) {
            this.setDefaultNodeSize(2000);
            this.getRootTreeNode().setChildOpen(0, false);
            this.getRootTreeNode().setChildOpen(0, true);
        }
    }
    super.onBrowserEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: You could increase the default node size otherwise you could override onBrowserEvent and manually expand all the tree notes http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTree.html#onBrowserEvent(com.google.gwt.user.client.Event)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. My code is going below:
`@Override
 public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
  if (event.getType().equals("mousedown")) {
   EventTarget target = event.getEventTarget();
   Element showMore = (Element)this.getElement().getLastChild().getFirstChild().getLastChild();
   // HARDCODE
   if(showMore.toString().replace("display: none;", "").equals(target.toString())) {
       this.setDefaultNodeSize(2000);
    this.getRootTreeNode().setChildOpen(0, false);
    this.getRootTreeNode().setChildOpen(0, true);
   }
  }
  super.onBrowserEvent(event);
 }`

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly wrong with my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just code from my comment with reasonable formatting:

```
@Override
public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
    if (event.getType().equals("mousedown")) {
        EventTarget target = event.getEventTarget();
        Element showMore = (Element)this.getElement().getLastChild().getFirstChild().getLastChild();
        // HARDCODE
        if(showMore.toString().replace("display: none;", "").equals(target.toString())) {
            this.setDefaultNodeSize(2000);
            this.getRootTreeNode().setChildOpen(0, false);
            this.getRootTreeNode().setChildOpen(0, true);
        }
    }
    super.onBrowserEvent(event);
}
```